# How to fix the frame of a modalviewcontroller when the animation is turned off?

Tags: ios

I have tried to set the animation of a modalviewcontroller to false and the frame adjustments is not working, but when i try to turn the animation on it will work normally. Is there a fix for this?
below is the context of my code:

```
MyModal *modal = [[MyModal alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyModal" bundle:nil];
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

modal.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 458, 230);
modal.view.superview.center = self.view.center;

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:modal animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is actually wrong. From your code;

```
 MyModal *modal = [[MyModal alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyModal" bundle:nil];
    modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    modal.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 458, 230);
    modal.view.superview.center = self.view.center;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:modal animated:NO]
```

The above code will never work because you are setting the frame of a view which is not yet created.

So, you can set the frame only after the new view is created or presented. 
In your `MyModal` viewcontroller, set the frame in `viewDidAppear` (**take care not to do it in `viewWillAppear`**)

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
      // code to set the frame here

 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I keep putting it inside viewWillAppear and viewDidload, seems that i forgot the viewDidAppear :D

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,you should take the code

```
modal.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 458, 230);
modal.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

to the MyModal's  -(void)viewDidLoad or -(void)viewWillAppear  method.

Launch view from nib needs more time than code;Before you launch view to memory,the nil modal.view's frame has already reset,then loads the nib's frame.As you turn off the animation, animation needs time to show,then,the frame could be resize.

Comment: friend,please add this as a comment. Not an answer.